# Why does my document 'error' when using '%'

Tags: errors, symbols

I am designing gamecards in `LaTeX`

Everything is going pretty ok so far but when i try to insert the `%`-sign for a question about percentages my file keeps giving errors. 
I tried putting the percentage between dollarsigns because i know just `%` will make it a 'remark' and that the dollarsign makes it 'mathematical data'.

Whats the reason for the error?

```
P.s. the error says: file ended while scanning use of \kaart. ...
```

Codesample:

```
{\kaart{Bekijk statistiek kaart F: 

Schat het percentage mensen dat als lievelingseten spaghetti opgaven, je mag er slechts $ 2% $ langs zitten. } { $ 11% $}}
```

Comment: `%` is a comment character, leading to errors (in most cases). You want to use `\%` or, better use `siunitx` and `\SI{11}{\percent}` for example. There's `\textpercent` also

Comment: Is this only with the %-sign or is are there more signs i should be aware of that have the same 'problem'

Comment: (La)TeX knows some command symbols like `%`, `#`, `_`, `$` etc. They all must be escaped with \, i.e. `\%`, `\#`, `\_`, `\$` to get their literal meaning, otherwise, they act as commands, switching to a certain behaviour, like `$` entering the math mode

Comment: That is if you want to use them as a textsymbol not a command right?

Comment: Yes, exactly this way. To prevent an accidental misuse, there are some commands that display those characters, like `\textpercent`, `\textdollar`

Comment: This should be explained in *every* introduction to LaTeX that deserves its name.

Comment: I have to correct myself: There's no `\textpercent` command, apparently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `%` if you want to write the `%` character directly.

The `%` character is reserved to indicate a comment after which everything is ignored. This is no problem at the end of a line, but the `%` should not occur in between, say, `$ 11 % $`, because this way TeX has entered math mode which is not correctly closed (unless there's a stray `$` following in one of the next lines. So this most likely leads to errors.

Use `\%` or for better spacing, use the `siunitx` package and say `\SI{11}{\percent}` for example.

Here's some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

% How not to be seen

There are some ways to type a literal \% character:

\begin{itemize}
  \item Say \verb!\%! and it will print \%
  \item Say \textbackslash verb!\%! in verbatim mode and it will print \verb!%!
  \item Say \verb!\SI{11}{\percent}! and it will print \SI{11}{\percent}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]