# Percent notation

Tags: math-mode, document-classes

Apologies if this is a too obvious question

How to type the "Percentage" sign in .tex ? Eg. 10 followed by the percentage.

Thank you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311221/117534, or perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339191/117534

Answer (score 17):

It's simply `\%`. You can use it in or out of math mode.

Answer (score 7):

TH.'s version would be the easiest. Another way would be to use `siunitx`. That is useful if you want units to be set the right way (concerning line breaking behavior, spacing etc.). It works for many units, so it would be a uniform markup, even if you need more than only the percent.

In your preamble:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

Later on:

```
\SI{10}{\percent}
```

Comment: It never occurred to me to treat percent as a unit. Is the space `\SI` puts between the number and the unit common for percentages? Now I'm curious what Knuth does in TAOCP and Concrete Mathematics as well as what is done in the GTM series.

Comment: @TH. Well, I've seen it in some documents, but not in many (most have regular space). One big advantage is concerning line breaks. My point is just that if you use it as unit you should also mark it up as such.